# login and redirect after wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

Is this idea is possible or not ?

When If administrator user login wp-admin panel from http://domain.ltd/wp-admin ; could we redirect to some external page like http://domain.ltd/my-newadmin ? Is this possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's possible using the filter [`wp_login`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wp_login). In this example, the redirection occurs if the user has the `administrator` capability.

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'so_14005301_redirect_admin_login', 10, 2 );

function so_14005301_redirect_admin_login( $user_login, $user )
{
    if( array_key_exists( 'administrator', $user->caps ) )
    {
        wp_redirect( site_url( 'new-admin/', 'http' ), 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

---

**Code reference:**

- function [`site_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url)
- [`wp_login`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/user.php#L64) hook
- function [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

---

**Variable reference:**
Contents of the `$user` parameter received by the function callback:

```
WP_User Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [user_login] => my_name
            [user_pass] => $P$BAdksWhVu4gZlZPZnv0m/VuUjsS3/Z0
            [user_nicename] => my_name
            [user_email] => email@gmail.com
            [user_url] => 
            [user_registered] => 2012-12-15 12:12:20
            [user_activation_key] => 
            [user_status] => 0
            [display_name] => my_name
        )

    [ID] => 1
    [caps] => Array
        (
            [administrator] => 1
        )

    [cap_key] => wp_capabilities
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [0] => administrator
        )

    [allcaps] => Array
        (
            [switch_themes] => 1
            [edit_themes] => 1
            [activate_plugins] => 1
            [edit_plugins] => 1
            [edit_users] => 1
            [edit_files] => 1
            [manage_options] => 1
            [moderate_comments] => 1
            [manage_categories] => 1
            [manage_links] => 1
            [upload_files] => 1
            [import] => 1
            [unfiltered_html] => 1
            [edit_posts] => 1
            [edit_others_posts] => 1
            [edit_published_posts] => 1
            [publish_posts] => 1
            [edit_pages] => 1
            [read] => 1
            [level_10] => 1
            [level_9] => 1
            [level_8] => 1
            [level_7] => 1
            [level_6] => 1
            [level_5] => 1
            [level_4] => 1
            [level_3] => 1
            [level_2] => 1
            [level_1] => 1
            [level_0] => 1
            [edit_others_pages] => 1
            [edit_published_pages] => 1
            [publish_pages] => 1
            [delete_pages] => 1
            [delete_others_pages] => 1
            [delete_published_pages] => 1
            [delete_posts] => 1
            [delete_others_posts] => 1
            [delete_published_posts] => 1
            [delete_private_posts] => 1
            [edit_private_posts] => 1
            [read_private_posts] => 1
            [delete_private_pages] => 1
            [edit_private_pages] => 1
            [read_private_pages] => 1
            [delete_users] => 1
            [create_users] => 1
            [unfiltered_upload] => 1
            [edit_dashboard] => 1
            [update_plugins] => 1
            [delete_plugins] => 1
            [install_plugins] => 1
            [update_themes] => 1
            [install_themes] => 1
            [update_core] => 1
            [list_users] => 1
            [remove_users] => 1
            [add_users] => 1
            [promote_users] => 1
            [edit_theme_options] => 1
            [delete_themes] => 1
            [export] => 1
            [administrator] => 1
        )

    [filter] => 
)
```

Comment: @FatihToprak, I should have documented the key functions and hooks, updated the Answer for future visitors ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Peter's Login Redirect plugin for this. It's great (as the plugin ratings suggest).

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/

Comment: Thank you but i dont want to usage any plugin my project